# Stone heads in Lhe a Rhemen

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

During the quest "The bronze beneath the lake" you're searching the Lhe a Rhemen ruins. There are some stone heads there that you can interact with, and they ask you a question that suggests that I might be able to earn a bonus of some kind. Answering their question makes a symbol on the walls glow, but nothing else happens.

I solved the quest itself, so I know that all the stone heads and other stuff in the ruins aren't needed for that.

Is there still something else to be done in those ruins? And how do I get those stone heads to do anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you answer the questions, symbols on the wall light up - make note of those symbols. Then kill the spider matriarch, she will drop a soul vessel. Behind her in the chest is a quest item and a mediocre spear. Take the spear to one of the earlier rooms with a head that wasn't initially lit up. there's a an oval shaped area on the floor you can click that talks about standing on symbols.

Place two characters on the symbols on the floor that match the ones that lit up. Take one character with the soul vessel and walk up to the small chamber under the face. There will be an event, and a pillar back in the room will glow. You can then enchant the spear using that now glowing pillar. I wound up with an exceptional spear with some other stats. Unsure if it does anything to the character that walks up to the small cubicle; I didn't notice any changes.